# My navbar on desktop responsive does not show up the same way as on a mobile phone even if the codes are the same

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, navbar

The snippet isnt working but my question is for some reason the navbar on resizing the browser does not look the same as when it is viewed in the mobile phone and I am not sure why I am using media queries, attached are photos.

Desktop version of navbar

[image]

On an iphone 6

[image]

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0064a4;
}
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#navbar5 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: #00a7d7;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #00a7d7;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #0064a4;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  /* padding:13px 10px; */
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #0096C1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #00a7d7;
  color: #0064a4;
}
ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #00a7d7;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .anon>.col-md-offset-0 {
    margin: 0 12%;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-brand img {
    width: 120px;
  }
  body {
    padding-top: 89px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 8px 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  /* since 3.1.0 */
  .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example5">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="cophyright logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="copyright.html">
  COPYRIGHT
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="copyright.html#cpy">WHAT IS COPYRIGHT?</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#cvcp">WORKS INCLUDED</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#notcp">WORKS EXCLUDED</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#rights">COPYRIGHTS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#limit1">LIMITATIONS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#own">OWNERSHIP</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="copyright.html#term">TERM OF PROTECTION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="protection.html">PROTECTION</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap.min.css overwrite your custom css. So call this sequence: First call bootstrap then custom.css

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https:custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Sorry in my file the load order is already like that so I dont think thats the problem.